# XSLT: For each with condition

Tags: xml, xslt

Currently, when I transform the XML through XSLT, it generated for all the nodes but I would like to output based on below condition

For any node, when `Reason_Code = AA` check the value of `Auth1` and bring it to previous node and capture the values for other tags in the same node. Please advise

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ns0:File xmlns:ns0="http://yourcompany.com/textschema/mapping/item.xsd">
    <Detail>
        <empty1>75500013</empty1>
        <empty2>00001N</empty2>
        <Reason_Code>B6</Reason_Code>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <empty1>75500012</empty1>
        <empty2>000011</empty2>
        <Reason_Code>AA</Reason_Code>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <empty1>4453252243</empty1>
        <empty2>0004235</empty2>
        <Auth1>AAA</Auth1>
        <Reason_Code>AA</Reason_Code>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <empty1>75500016</empty1>
        <empty2>00002N</empty2>
        <Reason_Code>B3</Reason_Code>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <empty1>75500018</empty1>
        <empty2>000014</empty2>
        <Reason_Code>AA</Reason_Code>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <empty1>43524433</empty1>
        <empty2>000415</empty2>
        <Auth1>BBB</Auth1>
        <Reason_Code>AA</Reason_Code>
    </Detail>
</ns0:File>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="http://yourcompany.com/textschema/mapping/item.xsd">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration = "yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Items_All>
            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:File/Detail">
                <Item>
                    
                    
                    <Item_ID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="empty1"/>
                    </Item_ID>
                    
                    <File_ID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="empty2"/>
                    </File_ID>
                    
                    <Auth>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Auth1"/>
                    </Auth>
                    
                    <Reason_Code>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Reason_Code"/>
                    </Reason_Code>
                    
                </Item>
                
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Items_All>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output generated:**

```
<Items_All xmlns:ns0="http://yourcompany.com/textschema/mapping/item.xsd">
   <Item>
      <Item_ID>75500013</Item_ID>
      <File_ID>00001N</File_ID>
      <Auth/>
      <Reason_Code>B6</Reason_Code>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Item_ID>75500012</Item_ID>
      <File_ID>000011</File_ID>
      <Auth/>
      <Reason_Code>AA</Reason_Code>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Item_ID>4453252243</Item_ID>
      <File_ID>0004235</File_ID>
      <Auth>AAA</Auth>
      <Reason_Code>AA</Reason_Code>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Item_ID>75500016</Item_ID>
      <File_ID>00002N</File_ID>
      <Auth/>
      <Reason_Code>B3</Reason_Code>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Item_ID>75500018</Item_ID>
      <File_ID>000014</File_ID>
      <Auth/>
      <Reason_Code>AA</Reason_Code>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Item_ID>43524433</Item_ID>
      <File_ID>000415</File_ID>
      <Auth>BBB</Auth>
      <Reason_Code>AA</Reason_Code>
   </Item>
</Items_All>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<Items_All xmlns:ns0="http://yourcompany.com/textschema/mapping/item.xsd">
    <Item>
        <Item_ID>75500013</Item_ID>
        <File_ID>00001N</File_ID>
        <Auth/>
        <Reason_Code>B6</Reason_Code>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Item_ID>75500012</Item_ID>
        <File_ID>000011</File_ID>
        <Auth>AAA</Auth>
        <Reason_Code>AA</Reason_Code>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Item_ID>75500016</Item_ID>
        <File_ID>00002N</File_ID>
        <Auth/>
        <Reason_Code>B3</Reason_Code>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Item_ID>75500018</Item_ID>
        <File_ID>000014</File_ID>
        <Auth>BBB</Auth>
        <Reason_Code>AA</Reason_Code>
    </Item>
</Items_All>
```

Currently, when I transform the XML through XSLT, it generated for all the nodes but I would like to output based on below condition

For any node, when `Reason_Code = AA` check the value of `Auth1` and bring it to previous node and capture the values for other tags in the same node. Please advise

Comment: You seem to have four `Detail` elements with that `Reason_Code` having the value `AA` in your input sample. Your verbal description "when Reason_Code = AA check the value of Auth1 and bring it to previous node and capture the values for other tags in the same node" doesn't explain clearly which nodes have to be merged. Is that any group of adjacent `Detail` elements with `Reason_Code` being `AA`? Can you use XSLT 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following to get your desired result:

> If you mean to copy the matched `Auth1` value to the previous node and suppress the matched `Detail` element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://yourcompany.com/textschema/mapping/item.xsd">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration = "yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Items_All>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Items_All>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Detail">
        <Items>
            <Item_ID>
                <xsl:value-of select="empty1"/>
            </Item_ID>
                    
            <File_ID>
                <xsl:value-of select="empty2"/>
            </File_ID>
            
            <Auth>
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1][name()]/Auth1"/>
            </Auth>
            
            <Reason_Code>
                <xsl:value-of select="Reason_Code"/>
            </Reason_Code>
        </Items>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Detail[Reason_Code='AA' and Auth1]"/>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```